# Open Sockjs inside an application

Tags: websocket, sockjs

I want to create an application where on page3 users start communicating via a sockjs websocket (they go through page1 and page2 to reach page 3). The code is working fine but I dont know why!

```
// Global scope
var sock;

// Inside a function page3, this is invoked when Page3 loads for the first time
function page3(){
   // Local scope
   sock= new SockJS("localhost:8080/messages);
   sock.onopen= function(){
   ....
   };

   sock.onmessage= function(data){
   ....
   };   
}
```

My question is - when a message is sent from the server how is `sock.onmessage` accessed by program execution even though it is 'seen' only when Page3 is loaded the first time  which is when `function page3()` is called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my own answer. 
 
 
The question is actually related to visibility of event listeners on the client. And the answer to that is - all event listeners on the client, once activated (flow of program execution having "seen" them) remain active until they are removed. 
 
So in the above case, even though `function page3()` was "seen" by program execution only once - when Page3 was loaded for the first time, `sock.onmessage` becomes activated as a (client) event listener during that `page3()` function call and continues to remain active until the socket is closed. 
 
As such, there is no need for an explicit `page3()` function call to trigger `sock.onmessage`. It (`sock.onmessage`) will keep listening to socket events sent by the server.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `sock` is not imported (the error message is saying that it is whats undefined)

Perhaps if you could share more of the code we could see why